# bash -c variable resolution in subshell

Tags: bash

How do I resolve a variable in a subshell inside of "bash -c"?

In the following, the second subshell -- the one with an "echo" inside -- resolves correctly.  The first subshell -- with "touch" -- does not.

```
/bin/bash -c "\
A=/tmp/foo; \
echo $( touch \$A;  ); \
echo $( echo in subshell, \$A; ); \
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply, because the subshell is evaluated from your current shell and not from your subshell. Escaping the `$()` will make it work as you expected:

```
/bin/bash -c "\
A=/tmp/foo; \
echo \$( touch \$A;  ); \
echo \$( echo in subshell, \$A; ); \
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using double quotes, Bash is evaluating the whole string first, then executes it.

Replace your first line with `/bin/bash -c echo “\` and you will see the following is the code `bash -c` is attempting to execute.

```
/bin/bash -c  echo "\
…


touch \$A;  ); echo $( echo in subshell, \$A; ); "
echo in subshell, \$A; ); "
touch \$A;  ); echo $( echo in subshell, \$A; ); 
touch \$A;  
echo in subshell, \$A; ); 
echo in subshell, \$A;
```

Use single quotes instead.

Comment: I improved the formatting of your answer, however I think it needs your attention as it is unclear what you meant by `...` in your explanation.